# How do paths work in Vue.component() statement?

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

I am trying to learn Laravel and Vue properly, after an initial attempt back in the spring. I'm still pretty new to both though.

I am using Laravel 8.x in Windows 10 along with Vue 2.6.12. I am working my way through a video on combining Vue with Laravel. The video is for an older version of Laravel, probably 5.5, and probably a slightly older Vue as well so that may well be the nature of my problem. Here's the link to the video. I'm at about the 8:00 minute mark.

The problem I'm having is that when I try to execute my code, Laravel doesn't see my Articles component.

My app.js file is at /resources/assets/js/app.js. Here is the code:

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = required('vue');
Vue.component ('Articles', require('./components/Articles.vue'));
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

The file that contains the script tag is at /resources/views/welcome.blade.php. Here is the code:
<!doctype html>

```
<html lang="{{  app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<title>Larticles App</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <div class="container">
    <Articles></Articles>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}">console.log("Made it to here!");</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The Article component is at /resources/assets/js/components/Articles.vue. Here is the code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Articles</h2>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Articles",
    beforeCreate() {
        console.log("Articles - beforeCreate()");
    },
    created() {
        console.log("Articles - created()");
    }, 
    beforeMount() {
        console.log("Articles - beforeMount()");
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log("Articles - mounted");
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
#app {
    background-color: gold;
    color: blue;
}
</style>
```

What do I need to change to make this work? I *think* the issue is the require portion of the Vue.component statement in app.js but I've tried every variation I can think of without success. I can't think of anything else to try! I can't find anything in the Vue manual on special syntax for this statement in Vue or Laravel.

I should mention some things. I've deviated *slightly* from what he does in the video as part of my troubleshooting. I've capitalized Articles in the first parameter of the Vue.component statement and I've also capitalized it in the container div of the welcome.blade.php file. (Initially, I wrote it all lower case in each of those places but it didn't work that way either.) I've also added several console.log statements in the components lifecycle hooks and in the script tag. Absolutely none of them appear in the console though.

Also, for some reason, my IDE, VS Code, insists on displaying  in red in the welcome.blade.php. Red always makes me think of errors but there is no error message of any kind. If I write those tags as  (and change the app.js accordingly), they stay red so I don't think this is a casing issue.

I should also mention that the Inspector shows the  as . Shouldn't it be showing exactly what I have in my welcome.blade.php file?

Answer (score 0):

Use lower case letters when importing the component

```
<articles></articles>
```

Comment: I tried changing only that but it didn't work. Still no error messages, the <articles></articles> markup in app.js looks exactly the same in the inspector, and nothing is written to the console.

Comment: @Henry Try a npm run watch

Comment: And move your `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}">console.log("Made it to here!");</script>` in the head tag

Comment: @Mihal - I was already running npm run watch but I stopped it with CTRL-C and started again but it still doesn't work. My trivial component doesn't show up and there's nothing in the console. I also moved the script tag to the head but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set each component you're reuire as default. Then use lower case as mentioned above. See below.

```
Vue.component ('Articles', require('./components/Articles.vue').default);
<articles></articles>
```

Comment: I tried each of these variations: Vue.component('articles', require(./components/Articles.vue'));     Vue.component('Articles', require(./components/Articles.vue'));   Vue.component('Articles', require(./components/Articles.vue').default);   Vue.component('articles', require(./components/Articles.vue').default);   but none of them worked.